# how to suppress 'The declaration isn't referenced' Dart Analysis warning for a file?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I have a generated dart file in my project that has some unused methods -- these unused methods are causing the Dart Analysis server in Android Studio to give a warning about each unused method.

The warning looks like this:
`info: The declaration '<method name>' isn't referenced. (unused_element at [<app name>] lib/Models/<file name>.g.dart:<line number of method>)`

How does one suppress these warnings just for the generated file?

Answer (score 8):

From Step 5 [here](https://dash-overflow.net/articles/getting_started/) (the whole article is well worth reading)

> Warnings in generated files do not matter to you.
> Generated files are out of your control. You shouldn’t edit them, and probably shouldn’t care about how the generated code looks like either.
> As such, instead of polluting your IDE with tons of pointless warning, simply disabling the linter on generated files is enough. This can be done by adding some code to your analysis_options.yaml.
> In our case, we will use both json_serializable and Freezed, so the code what we want to add is:

```
analyzer:
  exclude:
    # ignore warnings in files from json_serializable, built_value and most generators
    - "**/*.g.dart"
    # ignore warnings in files generated by Freezed specifically.
    - "**/*.freezed.dart"
```

Comment: this doesn't work to me. "issues" are still there.
Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

As a workaround it can be ignored with

```dart
// ignore: unused_element
_func_dart_complains_about() {}
```

or

```dart
// ignore_for_file: unused_element

...

_func_dart_complains_about() {}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a general issue with nested functions. If you're declaring a local function within a parent function, return the same function using a return statement for the parent function.

Like in the below example, if I wouldn't `return max();` inside the parent `void MainMax()` I'd get the error `The declaration '<method name>' isn't referenced`. Do check and return proper nested functions.

```
void mainMax(int a, int b, int c) {
  void max(){
  if(a>b && a>c){
  print (a);
  } else if (b>a && b>c){
  print (b);
  } else{ 
  print (c);
    }  
  }
max();
}
```